# Combine ARRAYS of unequal length

Tags: php

I need help of combination of two arrays in php.

What I have:

```
numbers = (1, 2,3,4,5,6);
letters = ('q', 'w', 'e', 'r');
```

What I need:

```
1 q 
2 w
3 e
4 r
5 
6
```

Important: I will never know how many items "numbers" or "letters" array contains (only that these are never equal in length), this varies per case.

So far following has gotten me closest to goal, but this submits all the letters to each number all together :

```
function array_combine2($arr1, $arr2) {
   return array_combine(
        array_intersect_key($arr1, $arr2), 
        array_intersect_key($arr2, $arr1));
}
foreach(array_combine2($number,$array) as $n1 => $a1)
{
    echo $n1 . $a1."<br>";
}
```

Comment: What if `letters` is longer than `numbers`, what do you use as the keys for the extra letters?

Comment: What are the values for the extra numbers? Empty strings? `null`?

Comment: the value is null

Comment: Will `$numbers` ever be shorter than `$letters`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`count()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) and [`array_fill()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php) to generate a "blank array" and then overlay that array with the `+` operator.

See: [Array Operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php)

```
$num = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$let = array('a', 'b', 'c');

$overlay = array_fill(0, count($num), NULL);
$sample = array_combine($num, $let + $overlay);

var_dump($sample);
```

**Output:**

```
array(5) {
  [1]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "b"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "c"
  [4]=>
  NULL
  [5]=>
  NULL
}
```

Comment: You only need `count($num) - count($let)`

Comment: No, for the code to work you need the `count()` of the whole array.

Comment: I see. My method would work if you used `array_merge` instead of `+`.

Comment: Does this handle the case where `$num` is shorter than `$let`?

Comment: The benefit of doing it with `+` is that if you are applying this to many different `$let` arrays, you don't need to run `count()` for all of them, just the first `$num`.

Comment: @Valentino No, but usually the solution is to use [`array_slice()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) on `$let` to make sure it's not longer than `$num`. This is usually because `$num` usually represents headers, and `$let` represents csv rows, and you typically won't care about "extra" data.

Answer (score 0):

```
function custom_arr_combine($numbers, $letters) {
   $lengthMax = count($numbers);
   if ($lengthMax < count($letters))
       $lengthMax = count($letters);

   $new_arr = [];
   for($i = 0; $i < $lengthMax; $i++) {
      $key = "";
      if (isset($numbers[$i]))
         $key = $numbers[$i];

      $value = "";
      if (isset($letters[$i]))
         $value = $letters[$i];

      $new_arr[$key] = $value;
   }
   return $new_arr;
}

// test
$numbers = array(1, 2,3,4,5,6);
$letters = array('q', 'w', 'e', 'r');
$arr = custom_arr_combine($numbers, $letters);

foreach($arr as $nbr => $letter) 
    echo $nbr. " ". $letter. "\n";
```

Can this custom function help you in this [link](https://repl.it/@AbdellatifDerbe/ConcernedTautQuotient)
[image]

Comment: It is recommended that you post code and output here on SO rather than links and images to answers.

Comment: THank you so mush Abdellatif You had the right Answer Thank you so mush have a good day

Comment: Abdellatif can you help me what if the two array that i have is $numbers = array('a','b','b','d','a','b');
$letters = array('q', 'w', 'e', 'r');

Comment: The problem here is that you cannot have multiple of the same key in an associative array. 
You could, however, have unique keys each of whose corresponding values are arrays, and those arrays have multiple elements for each key.

As I write the result will be like that:
       array(
             'a' => array('q', ''),
             'b' => array('w', 'e', ''),
             'd' => array('d')
      )